# changing the position of the search icon

Tags: android, menu, searchview

I use SearchView in OptionsMenu:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    </menu>
```

In main activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.arrow, null);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        setupSearchView(searchItem);
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }
```

The search icon located on the right in menu. How to change its position in my menu? I want that it is located left.

Comment: That would violate the Android design guidelines: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: If I still want to break the principles of design android. Is there a way to do this?